# Azure scheduled task timeout after 30 seconds

Tags: azure, timeout, retrypolicy

Couldn't find answer to this so any help is welcome. One of my scheduled tasks in Azure runs large reports creation but it's timing out because the scheduler throws a timeout error after 30 seconds, then retries 5 more times! My database is very large and the script takes about 7 minutes to finish. Any suggestion on how to increase the timeout and/or how to cancel the retries using the portal?

Someone suggested to add the following to the retry policy in the action but did not explain enough:

```
 "retryPolicy":
    {
     "retryType": "none"
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C#, you can specify the RetryPolicy in the JobAction. Let me try to see I describe this better in the following...

Assuming that your credentials, cloud service (not to be confused with the other cloud service as in PaaS) and a job collection are in place, you would create a SchedulerClient as such...

```
SchedulerClient mySchedClient = new SchedulerClient(
          cloudServiceName: myCloudServiceName,
          jobCollectionName: myJobCollectionName,
          credentials: myCertCloudCredentials);
```

The next step is to call CreateOrUpdate and inside the parameters is where you can specify the RetryPolicy. Here's a http job as an example...

```
JobCreateOrUpdateResponse jobCreateResponse = mySchedClient.Jobs.CreateOrUpdate(
    jobId: SomeNameForTheJob,
    parameters: new JobCreateOrUpdateParameters
       {
          Action = new JobAction
             {
                Type = JobActionType.Http,
                RetryPolicy = new RetryPolicy(RetryType.None),
                Request = new JobHttpRequest
                   {
                      Uri = new Uri("http://www.cnn.com"), 
                      Method = "GET"
                   }
             }
       });
```

Comment: @sagar did this actually work in your scenario? One can now alter the retry policy in the 'new' portal and as mentioned I have set the RetryPolicy to none, but my job still completes as "Error" and the message states that it timed out after 30s.  As this is a web server, the job is (of course) still actually running on the server, but the scheduling system is not able to collect the results, which somewhat defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

there's no way to increase the time out for an azure scheduled job. unfortunately; hopefully it will be added soon.